# When click on search, the data displays, but when i click again, the data disappear

Tags: php

When click on search, the data displays, but when I click again, the data disappear. I know its a simple thing but I really cant figure it out. im trying to explain as much as i can.

```
Search Engine: <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter keywords..." />
<input type="submit" name="search_product" value="Search now"/>


   </form>

 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("tutorial");


    if(empty($_GET['search'])){

        echo "No Search results";
    }   
    if(!empty($_GET['search'])){

    if (isset($_GET['search_product'])){

                 $search_value = $_GET['search'];

                  $query = "SELECT * FROM `blob` WHERE keyword LIKE '%$search_value%'";


              $run = mysql_query($query);

              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run)){

                $name = $row['name'];
                $categorie = $row['categorie'];
                $lieu = $row['lieu'];
                $image = $row['image'];


                echo ("<div style='text-align:center;' style=width:300px; align='center';><h2><p>Nom du Produit: $name</h2> <strong>Categorie:</strong> $categorie <p><strong>Lieu:</strong> $lieu </p></p></div>");    
                echo "<div style='margin-left:630px;'>";?><?php echo"<img src=$image <height='150' width='150'>"?> <?php echo "</div>";
                echo "<hr/>";


              } 
    }

    }
```

Comment: Explain your question in details

Comment: When click on search, the data displays, but when i click again, the data disappear. i know its a simple thing but i really cant figure it out

Comment: I think which is due to your first if statment

Comment: Maybe i am blind, but i cant see where you have the click button, maybe your should check if your search-value is empty when you click second one.

Comment: on second time are you leaving the `search_box` empty ?

Comment: can you show your code for HTML form?

Comment: the first "if"   if(empty($_GET['search'])){

        echo "No Search results";
    }   

is to check if its empty, it works fine and the results display,. BUT when the results is still here, and i click again on search, it removes all the search results

Comment: I am not sure try using mysql_fetch_assoc($run) instead of mysql_fetch_array($run)

Comment: @kk12391 yes the second time i leave the search_box empty

Comment: @AsraafAliBhuttoo Your code is saying that if the search is empty then i will go to first `if` block. so what you're getting ?

Comment: @kk12391 if search is empty first time, it says " no results" but next time when i search something, it displays the result, but when i click search again, the results disappear

Comment: @AsraafAliBhuttoo by default it is showing `No Search results` right?

Comment: yes @kk12391 it showing No Search results by default

Comment: @AsraafAliBhuttoo I've added an answer check that.

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the search data `$search_value = $_GET['search']`
After click on the search button again.
If you don't get any data in `$search_value`  then in query you will not find any of the data.

Comment: still.. the second time i press search again, the data disappear... and i no its a small error to correct...but cant find it..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search']) )
{
    $var = $_GET['search'];
    echo $var;//var_dump($var);
    echo '</br>';
}
if(isset($_GET['search']) && empty($_GET['search']) )
{
    echo "empty";
}
?>
<form action = "" method = "GET">
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Enter keywords..." />
<input type="submit" name="search_product" value="Search now"/>
</form>
```

I'm showing you a demo this may help you.